# Firestore: Get server timestamp value for making client-side time comparisons

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a document retrieved from Firestore that has a date field X. I want to know if X is a date in the future or not. How would I do this in JavaScript from the browser?

It would be best if I could get a server-side timestamp S for this and then in the browser I would make the comparison X > S? How do I get S?

I know I have use a placeholder value for the server timestamp when uploading documents and doing queries but I want a concrete value for the timestamp here.

Comment: The problem is that every round trip between your app and the server incurs some unknown latency.  So if you want an "exact" server time, you're out of luck, because you'll have no idea how much time any given call has spent going either direction.  I suggest you find some other way of doing what you want, unless you're willing make guesses about what the server's sense of time really is.  Or, you could just assume that the client's clock is close enough, which is what pretty much all apps do.

Comment: @DougStevenson I only need an accuracy of a few hours or even a day. A little latency isn't important. It's probably rare, but I'd rather not rely on the client clock if possible as weird things will happen in the app logic if the clock is wrong by a lot. Is there a way to get the server timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an estimate of the server time, simply write a document with a field that contains the server time sentinel token as a value, then immediately read the document back and look at the Timestamp that the server actually wrote.  Then delete the document, of course.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem that practical as it'll use up my Firestore quota. Just a thought but is it possible to get accurate dates from the JWT token somehow or those use the client timer too? Maybe you can get the expiry date of the refresh token which should get updated every hour?

Comment: You only need to do it once per client and retain the result, unless you are paranoid about people changing their clocks.

Comment: So I'm looking at firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult() and the issuedAtTime/expirationTime times seem to be based on the server side clock (I tried changing my clock to confirm this). Could I rely on these times and this API? I'm not sure if these are the refresh token values or not that get updated each hour. Failing that I could consider the document writing solution if there's really no better option.

Comment: I don't know. You're going pretty far outside the bounds of the original question now.