# Firebase Admin Timestamp

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am working with Firebase Admin SDK and having issues with Timestamp. When comparing Timestamps from my documents I was getting unexpected results. On further inspection when printing the Timestamp it appears to be empty. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.listingEndOfDayCheck = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('* * * * *')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    
    let timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

    try {
      const querySnapshot = await db.collection('listings').get();

      // Create an empty promises array for collecting the promise responses from each update call below.
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log('Printing doc.data().endDate', doc.data().endDate);
          console.log(timestamp);

          if (doc.data().endDate) {
            if (doc.data().endDate < timestamp) {
              console.log('Date is older than now.');
            } else {
              console.log('Date is further in the future than now.');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

The print out for endDate shows.

> Printing doc.data().endDate Timestamp { _seconds: 1631041200,
> _nanoseconds: 0 }

The print out for Timestamp shows.

> ServerTimestampTransform {}

Answer (score 0):

The `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is **not** a value, but an instruction to the database server to write the current timestamp.

You cannot meaningfully use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` in client-side comparisons. You will have to write `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to a document, and then read that document back into your application to get an actual value to compare against.

Also see:

- [Firestore: Get server timestamp value for making client-side time comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292732/firestore-get-server-timestamp-value-for-making-client-side-time-comparisons)
- [Is firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714486/is-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-async)
- [Firebase serverTimestamp older than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518190/firebase-servertimestamp-older-than/62518314#62518314)

And more from these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+get+server+side+timestamp).